# write a function that receives a list of strings and return list of lists

Tags: python, string, list, performance, nested-lists

I can't find any similar solution for this specific question.

write a function that receives a list of strings and returns list of lists, each item in a group of lists has the same letters as the other items in that list (different order).

`(abc, acb, aab, aba) --> ((abc, acb), (aab, aba))`

this is the code that I have so far, but its not quite right,
first of all its runs in O(n^2) and I need a solution in O(n)
second, if there are more than 2 similarities the whole result isn't right.

```
def ex1(str_list: list = ()) -> list:
    result = []
        items = []
        for item in str_list:
            items.append(''.join(sorted(item)))
        for i in range(len(items)):
            for j in range(i):
                if items[i] == items[j]:
                    result.append([str_list[j], str_list[i]])

        return result
```

the solution I seek is using a dictionary and with time complexity of O(n)
example for

input: `['abc', 'acb', 'aab', 'aba', 'bac']`

Output: `[['abc', 'acb', 'bac'], ['aab', 'aba']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working example:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List, Tuple


def string_key(string: str) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
    """Returns a key which is unique on the characters in the string (ignoring ordering)."""
    return tuple(sorted(string))


def group_by_chars(data: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:
    """Group strings by the characters they contain, regardless of order."""
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for value in data:
        key = string_key(value)
        result[key].append(value)
    return list(result.values())


assert group_by_chars(["abc", "acb", "aab", "aba"]) == [["abc", "acb"], ["aab", "aba"]]
```

The trick is defining a function which maps values which belong to the same group to the same key, and putting each value into a bucket based on the output of that key function.

Another approach would be to use `sorted` and [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

from typing import List, Tuple


def string_key(string: str) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
    """Returns a key which is unique on the characters in the string (ignoring ordering)."""
    return tuple(sorted(string))


def alternate_group_by_chars(data: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:
    result = []
    for _key, group in groupby(sorted(data, key=string_key), string_key):
        result.append(list(group))
    return result
```

However this will return results in a different order (due to the necessary `sorted`) and think its less readable.

Comment: The latter will also not be O(N) but O(N logN)

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the grouping idiom and use the *sorted* string as a key:

```
>>> import collections
>>> data = ['abc', 'acb', 'aab', 'aba', 'bac']
>>> def group_by_letters(strings):
...     grouper = collections.defaultdict(list)
...     for string in strings:
...         grouper[tuple(sorted(string))].append(string)
...     return list(grouper.values())
...
>>> group_by_letters(data)
[['abc', 'acb', 'bac'], ['aab', 'aba']]
```